# How can I convert Selection to String in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to put a selection word to a string, something like :

```
Dim str As String

Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Select
Selection.Copy
str = Selection.Paste
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using copy and paste:

```
str = Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Text
```

Comment: thank you it's work 
have you any idea about this ?
```
With ActiveDocument
  .ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:=GetFolder & "\" & Split(str, ".")(0) & ".pdf", _
  ExportFormat:=wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, _
  OptimizeFor:=wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, _
  Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=True, _
  CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateNoBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
  BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
End With
```

Comment: That's an export to a PDF. If you have a new question, please start a new thread with more details about what problem you are having with that code.

Comment: okey 
this is the new question link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013610/invalid-file-name-error-80004005-vba-word